# Setting Checkbox in a Table Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Trying to set a checkbox inside a table. I thought it would be straightforward and similar to doing it in a form.

I can do this successfully with a form , but getting stuck when the checkbox is in a table.

When the checkbox is in a form I use:

```
 <form name="access_menu_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mybox_name" id="mybox_id" value="1">
 </form>

 document.access_menu_form.mybox_name.checked == true
```

Which works great!!

I know I am missing a key point about the DOM. Trying to set a checkbox that I have in table fails using a similar technique which fails:

My table:

```
 <table name="access_table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Area</th> 
      <th>Item</th> 
      <th>Access</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="mybox_name" id="mybox_id" value="1"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="mybox1_name" id="mybox1_id" value="1"></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

My script

```
 document.access_table.mybox_name.checked = false;
```

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mybox' of undefined

```
 document.mybox_name.checked = false;
```

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: Ha ha. So many people answered so quick and pretty much all the same! Thanks for the help guys. I did try that but I must have been missing something. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the 'checked' attribute
- let javascript find the checkbox using the following, document.getElementById('mybox_id')

Answer (score 1):

If you have IDs, the most straight-forward way is using `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('mybox_id').checked == true;
```

It will always work no matter where the element is residing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use javascript like this, you're typically accessing the id of the element, not the name.  Try this instead:

**To Check the value:**

```
if(document.getElementById('mybox_id').checked == false){
  // Do Stuff
}
```

**To Assign the value:**

```
document.getElementById('mybox_id').checked = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `document.getElementById('mybox_id').checked = false`!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('mybox_id').checked = false;
```

Will work anywhere (inside or outside of table).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the checkboxes in a form tag,which is wrapped with the table tag.That will fix your problem.